# IE11, Amazon S3, and a Rails proxy results in images not loading/request aborting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, proxy, internet-explorer-11

I'm stumped and hoping someone can offer insight...

I am building an app that requires images to appear from the same domain, so my Rails app has a simple image proxy for files stored on S3 servers (replaces requests to domain.com/bucket-name/... with s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/... and serves up file contents):

```
class ProxyController < ActionController::Base
    def proxy
        image_url = request.protocol + ENV['S3_HOST'] + "#{request.path}"
        response.headers['Cache-Control'] = "public, max-age=#{84.hours.to_i}"
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
        text = open(image_url, "rb").read
        render :text => text
      end
    end
```

Route in config/routes.rb:

```
get "/" + ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'] + "/*other" => "proxy#proxy"
```

Now in IE11 (the only IE I've tested so far), images are not loading:

```
<image src='/bucket-name/uploads/images/000/000/018/original/data?1456356347'/>
```

They have the little "X" failed image load box, and the network result in the Developer Tools reads "`(Aborted)`" as the result with 0B received.  The Rails server is receiving and completing the request:

```
Completed 200 OK in 1120ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

In all other browsers I'm able to load up image just fine.  This is occurring on local as well as Heroku-hosted production instances.

Is there something specific to IE that would affect proxying images?  Why would the request be aborted?  Let me know if there is any more information I can offer.  Thank you!

Comment: What's the mime type being returned? This blog post sounds like it might be relevant: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2609-internet-explorer-aborts-images-with-the-wrong-mime-type.htm

Comment: You, sir, are my hero.  There was no MIME type being sent along - manually including it in the headers has the image displaying.  Thank you!  Feel free to post an answer here and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE will abort an image download if the correct MIME type isn't being returned, or if no MIME type is present in the image response at all.